# Drupal site - jquery doesn't work on search results page

Tags: jquery, drupal

My custom jquery functions don't work on "search results" page and on "add material" page.

Pages urls are next:

- mysite/search/node/ - search results
- mysite/node/add - add material

So it seems, that when some modules run, my jquery functions are disabled. When I add a material - this bug is seen only by me, but every visitor of my site will be able to see search results. :(

Simple JS function works fine: I checked it with alert().

Any ideas, why does it happen? Thanks.

P.S. I have 2 jquery versions. May be, this fact is important. I manage them as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=path_to_theme()?>/js/jquery.1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<?php print $scripts ?>
```

Comment: it's really annoying that Drupal forces you to have a really old version of JQuery installed. Hacks like this wouldn't be necessary if Drupal hadn't got that wrong in the first place.

Comment: you are a little bit stuck, but you can load custom versions of jquery (kind of). Check out this module: http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Comment: Thank you, but update doesn't mean the latest version in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed my integrated version and have leaved only core version of jQuery. All work fine.
I think it's not a question anymore, but bug report. And it seems, that the bug is in drupal, cause on simple pages .noConflict() worked perfectly.

An advise to those, who has the same problem - use only core version and rewrite your scripts, if needed. Or you can also make some update with this [module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) (Thanks to [hross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107073/hross) for the link)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to the fact that you must use jQuery.noConflict() before loading the other library. Read [this](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/) article for some tips on loading two version of jquery.

Maybe just switch the lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=path_to_theme()?>/js/jquery.1.6.1.js"></script>
<?php print $scripts ?>
```

Comment: Interesting article, thank you. Unfortunately, when I switched the lines, my scripts stopped working at all. Print $scripts command prints drupal jquery core version. jquery.1.6.1.js - is my integrated version.